# Using JSON to store data inside a variable

Tags: ios, json

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to store the response from a JSON output because I want to show in a "ProfileViewController" the stats of the users and I'm trying to use the following function in order to store the information.

At the moment the output is fine, because the data is OK depending on the users, but now I have to store each one of the stats in a "variable" for each of the stats (I have 3) but when I run the code it didn't show my NSLog for Stars, Followers and Pictures...

Can you help me with that? The response is fine, now I just want to store each one of the stats in a single variable. How can I do that? What's wrong in my code?

**ProfileViewController** -> **fetchJson**:

```
-(void)fetchJson {

    NSString *usersPassword = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"login" account:@"account"];

    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"usersPassword=%@",usersPassword];
    NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com/profile.php"];

    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
    if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
    {
        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

        SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
        NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];

        NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)success);

        if(success == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");

            [_jsonArray removeAllObjects];
            _jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:data
                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                          error:&error];

            for(int i=0;i<_jsonArray.count;i++)
            {
                NSDictionary * jsonObject = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* stars = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"stars"];
                NSLog(@"Stars ==> %@", stars);

                NSDictionary * jsonObject2 = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* followers = [jsonObject2 objectForKey:@"followers"];
                NSLog(@"Followers ==> %@", followers);

                NSDictionary * jsonObject3 = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* photos = [jsonObject3 objectForKey:@"photos"];
                NSLog(@"Pictures ==> %@", photos);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**JSON output**:

```
{"success":1,"stars":50,"photos":50,"followers":50}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does a log of _jasonArray show?

Answer (score 0):

```
  _jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myNSData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSDictionary * jsonObject  = (NSDictionary *)_jsonArray;
```

and then check dictionary object.

Answer (score 0):

jsonData already contains the parsed response and as you have successfully retrieved success value from it as follows,

```
NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)success);
```

You can retrieve other value as follows,

```
[[jsonData objectForKey:@"stars"] integerValue]
```

and so on.

You didn't have to create foundation object by using following method

```
NSJSONSerialization
                  JSONObjectWithData:data
                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                  error:&error];
```

and following block of code is unnecessary,

```
for(int i=0;i<_jsonArray.count;i++)
{
      NSDictionary * jsonObject = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
      NSString* stars = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"stars"]
      NSLog(@"Stars ==> %@", stars);

      NSDictionary * jsonObject2 = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
      NSString* followers = [jsonObject2 objectForKey:@"followers"];
      NSLog(@"Followers ==> %@", followers);

      NSDictionary * jsonObject3 = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
      NSString* photos = [jsonObject3 objectForKey:@"photos"];
      NSLog(@"Pictures ==> %@", photos);
}
```